# GameObjects materials appearing in Editor but not in Build (disappearing) Problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-build, unity-editor

As you can see in the editor, I can see and control the player character, but in the build I can only move the player character, but I can't see it! also some other GameObjects materials doesn't appear on the build!
Please, what could be causing this problem? And how to fix it!

[Build Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDhPo.jpg)
[Editor Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfpAy.png)

Comment: not including the shader you need?

Comment: Excatly, but some other GameObjects don't appear too even with their materials default unity shader!

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool [UnityRuntimeInspector](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityRuntimeInspector) that may help you find out what happened to your materials or shaders in the build.

[image: Material]

[image: Shader]